# Java - allocation in enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, memory

I have small problem in java with allocation of my object in "enhanced for loop".
I tried something like this, which gives me later nullPointerException:

```
SomeClass tab[] = new SomeClass[100];
for( SomeClass x : tab){
  x = new SomeClass();
}
```

So... Earlier I code in C++ and It was possible to edit in any way (and sure also allocate memory) object, when just add & operator, like this:

```
SomeClass *tab = new SomeClass[100];
for( auto & x : tab){
  x = new SomeClass();
}
```

...and everything works well. But how is it in java? Is there any way to use this for loop when allocate some memory or not?

Comment: what do you mean when you say: "Is there any way to use this for loop when allocate some memory or not?"

Comment: Java doesn't have references or value assignment, so you're doomed unless you use lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use an enhanced for loop to initialize the elements of an array.  The declared variable, here `x`, is a separate variable that refers to the current element in the array.  It's `null` here because you just declared the array.  You are changing `x` to refer to a new `SomeClass`, but that doesn't affect the array at all.

```
0    | 1    | 2    | ...
-------------------------
|    |      |      | ...
v
null <--- x
```

After assignment to x:

```
0    | 1    | 2    | ...
-------------------------
|    |      |      | ...
v
null

x --> new SomeClass()
```

Java variables are different from C++ references in this behavior.  Assigning a Java reference variable does not affect anything else that might refer to the same object.

You must use an array access expression, which requires an index.  A standard `for` loop will work here.

```
SomeClass tab[] = new SomeClass[100];
for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
{
    tab[i] = new SomeClass();
}
```

Comment: Alternative: `Arrays.setAll(tab, i -> new SomeClass());`

Comment: Thanks rgettman :) OK, so still thinking, that C++ language is better than Java :P But sad is, that Java and also C# have more libs, that makes them better than old C++. Nvm :P Again - thanks 4 help ;)